# ExitProcess behaviour in Windows in relation to atexit handlers

Tags: windows, multithreading

I want to be able to catch any attempts of executing exit()/ExitProcess()/TerminateProcess() or any other such calls.

I thought about registering a handler with atexit(). This works fine for normal program termination (return from main()) or exit() calls (regardless of the thread that calls exit()), but ExitProcess() and TerminateProcess() bypass the handler I registered. 
[ExitProcess() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> Note that returning from the main function of an application results
>   in a call to ExitProcess.

But the observed behaviour is at least different in this regard.
Is there a method of registering a handler for process exit/termination what will always be called (except for external calls to TerminateProcess(), unhandled exceptions thrown by one of my threads or __failfast() calls, I'm guessing these are really impossible to catch). 
There is the dirty option of hooking ExitProcess(), but I'd rather not do that.

EDIT: just so this is clear: I'm interested in my own process, not monitoring / controlling another process.

Comment: Well, `atexit` is a C runtime library thing which Windows (`ExitProcess`) doesn't know or care about. `atexit` can only ever handle exit conditions that are known to the C runtime. And from Windows' point of view, returning from the main function will call `ExitProcess`, it's just that in C the runtime has its own main function where it sets up stuff like  `argv` which then calls *your* main function. So returning from *that* function will not immediately return to the OS, but rather to the C runtime again.

Comment: Oh, so that's why it works (I guess this can be easily checked with a debugger). From what I see Windows provides no API with this functionality, but I may not look where I should.

Comment: I didn't see anything along that lines either. Perhaps the reasoning is that when you need cleanup on exit you control your own exit anyway and can do so yourself. You *could* add a DLL which gets notified of impending process shutdown: *»The entry-point functions of all loaded dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) are called with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.«* But apart from that it doesn't look like you could detect it.

Comment: Adding a DLL that handles that is a little tricky, from what I see looking at what happens when ExitProcess() is called. You don't always control your own exit, you can have a third party library that calls exit(), or someone can create a remote thread inside your process and do just that.

Comment: Last I heard, `atexit` should work in the case of a call to ExitProcess, *provided* you are using the DLL version of the C runtime.  (Mentioned in the comments to [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141017-00/?p=43823).)  Are you using a statically linked runtime?

Comment: ... but I'm not sure why you're worried that your application might call ExitProcess() rather than exit(), can't you just search the source code?  Or perhaps even define a macro so that any references to ExitProcess will fail to compile?

Comment: My application runs third party code and I want to be able to know when it exits. This is an in-house tool, but I still don't have full control over the environment it will be used. As a fan of The Old New Thing I'm disappointed with myself that I did not knew about that post. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Kernel Mode Event a device driver can subscribe to in order to get notifications of terminations of processes. This is preferred over trying to inject a DLL into processes for API hooks due to the myriad number of internal and external ways that process may end.

Comment: I'd rather not deploy a kernel component just for controlling my own process. I'm not interested in other processes behaviour.